# Cannot get Battery Level

Tags: powershell, battery, wmic, powercfg

normally I used this command to get battery level

```
wmic Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining
```

but recently it started to give me: Win32_Battery - Alias not found.

So I read I should be using Powershell instead, so I tried

```
(Get-CimInstance Win32_Battery).EstimatedChargeRemaining
```

and

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery | Select-Object estimatedChargeRemainingü
```

but both commands gave me this error

[image: screenshot of error]

so something is wrong, that is realy wierd as I have a windows 8.1 laptop that has battery and this command:

```
powercfg /batteryreport
```

works fine, but I don't want to parse a file to get battery status, and the wierdest thing is that this above commands worked previously (so eather windows update did something or I don't know what could happen), also tried abovce commands on PowerShell x86 but its the same problem

So does anyone know where is: Win32_Battery class (it seems its absend on my machine, so how can I add it then?

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Answer (score 3):

Your first command gives me the same error on my Windows 10 machine (I do not have a Windows 8 machine any more).

Try:

`WMIC PATH Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining`

Specifically add PATH before Win32.

This works for me here.

[image]

Comment: nope, its still Not found: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6347325/107052248-b6565580-67cd-11eb-8fad-2a98395f99e3.png

how could this happen (it used to work)

Comment: There may have been an issue with the Windows Update that ran.  Run DISM from an Admin Command Prompt.  dism.exe   /online /cleanup-image  /restore-health  . Restart when done and test.

Comment: Another thought - just a thought - upgrade to Windows 10 as Windows 8 is now getting quite old.

Comment: I have Dell XPS (Touch screen) laptop and Windows 8.1 is quite good fit for it (got touch laptop just because I hated windows 8 on anything else that is not touch, even tried windows 10 on it and I went back to 8 because I didn't like it on it :)

Comment: Did you try the DISM Repair?

Comment: it doesn't work on windows 8.1  /restore-health is not recognized in this content

doh, windows updates suck, if I knew which update had broken that (even google is not helpful in this case :(

Comment: DISM does work, I have used it several times on Windows 8 / 8.1   . So your OS is damaged and needs repair or re-install. That is about the only option left.

Comment: eather dism is case  sensitive or I don't know what I ran, after trying again like:  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth it did started to do something so, hope it does something now :), will see

Comment: See what happens. I do not have a Windows 8 repair install in my notes. After dism completes, also run SFC /SCANNOW

Comment: Thanks, after running: Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
rebooted it now reports battery

not sure what was broken, but its fixed now :)

Comment: So all fixed - that is good.